# checking if a number is float in PHP

Tags: php, validation, floating-point

This is really weird. I have this piece of code.

```
$rewardAmt = $amt;
if(is_float($rewardAmt)){
      print_r("is float");die;
} else {
      print_r("is not float"); die;
}
```

value of $amt is 0.01. But it is going into else condition. So I did a var_dump of $amt. it says string(4)
So I decided to typecast $amt

```
   $rewardAmt = (float)$amt;
```

But the problem with this is even if the value of $amt is 1, it still gets typecast to float and goes into if condition, which shouldn't happen. Is there any other way to do this ? Thanks

Comment: whats weird is your use of `print_r`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the first line to

```
$rewardAmt = $amt+0;
```

$rewardAmt should be cast to a number.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with [`FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

```
if (filter_var($amount, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT))
{
     // good
}
```

Comment: I tried this but this results in the same prob as typecasting. If $amount = "0.12", it changes to float(0.12) , if it is "1", it changes to float(1)

Comment: perfect for validating a float or integer

Comment: worth notice that:

`string '0' -> 0 is NOT float` and 
`int 0 -> 0 is NOT float`

Answer (score 1):

You can check this by

```
$float = floatval($num); //Convert the string to a float
if($float && intval($float) != $float) // Check if the converted int is same as the float value...
{
    // $num is a float
}else{
    // $num is an integer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unary `+` operator, which will cast the string to the appropriate type (`int` or `float`), and then test the resulting data type with `is_float`:

```
$s = "3.00";
$n = +$s;
var_dump( $n ); // float(3)
var_dump( is_float($n) ); // true


$s = "3";
$n = +$s;
var_dump( $n ); // int(3)
var_dump( is_float($n) ); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [the documentation of is_float function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php):

> Note: To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as
> form input, which is always a string), you must use [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

The answer is using **is_numeric()** and not is_float().
This works also if the number tested is "0" or 0.