# Why is is_float() returning true for whole numbers?

Tags: php

I am confused by [**THIS ANSWER**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866713/checking-if-a-number-is-float-in-php).

1. Below code is not working

> ```
> $percentagediscount = $actualprice * ($discount/100);     
> $payableamt1 = $actualprice - $percentagediscount;      
> $payableamt = $payableamt1+0; 
> echo $payableamt;                                                  
> if(is_float($payableamt)){
>   print_r(" is float");
> }     
> else{
>   print_r(" is not float");
> }
> ```

```
OUTPUT: 200 is float
```

2. This is working when I test with

> ```
> $payableamt1 = 200;    
> $payableamt = $payableamt1+0; 
> echo $payableamt;     
> if(is_float($payableamt)){
>       print_r(" is float");
> }     
> else{
>         print_r(" is not float");
> }
> ```

```
OUTPUT: 200 is not float
```

Comment: i did not downvote. but pls try the formatting of your question (code). and add the test values you used for example 1.

Comment: If your var `$payableamt` in your first example is an integer, `is_float()` returns false. What's the value of that var?

Comment: plus: `PHP` is quite flexible when it comes to datatypes. it's not strict like `C++` or `Java` is. for example you can add a `float` to a `string` and still get a `float` and not an error: `$my_str=""; $my_float=1.1; $my_result=$my_str+$my_float; is_float($my_result); //true`

Comment: @northkildonan : i already mention what i get at `$payableamt1`. so no use of test values for other values.

Comment: @Paul : same value 200 and 'is float'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in your first snippet is, that you are doing a division (dividing by 100). In PHP there is no integer division operation, so any result (even if it is a whole number) is cast into a float value. Thus, `$payableamt = 200;` after the division is a float value.

See this ***[test](https://eval.in/221237)***:

```
$payableamt = 200;
var_dump($payableamt);
$payableamt2 = $payableamt / 3 * 3;
var_dump($payableamt2);
```

*Note: If you actually do `$payableamt2 = $payableamt / 1 * 1;` the second var will still be an `int` since the operation didn't require intermediate `float` calculation steps, see the second **[test](https://eval.in/221238)**.*

If you want to test if your result has no decimal digits, try

```
if (floor($payableamt) == $payableamt) {
    return '$payableamt is a whole number.';
}
```

You can use that test to cast your result to an int value again, see the third ***[test](https://eval.in/221242)***.

```
if (floor($payableamt2) == $payableamt2) {
    $payableamt2 = (int) $payableamt2;
}
```

Comment: deadman's anwser is not working. your answer is working but is it correct way.

Comment: why this is happen? what to do if i want to do?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking or what you want.

Comment: 1. when i divide with 100. it is showing float. 2. if i have to divide?

Comment: I am sorry. I guess the language barrier keeps me from assisting you further. Maybe you got a college/friend, who could rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

here is small sample code which i think should solve your problem

```
$amt = "0.001";
$amt2 = "1";

$amt = (float)$amt;
$amt2 = (float)$amt2;

if(fmod($amt,1) >  0)
{
     echo "amt is float: ".$amt;
}
else
{
    $amt = intval($amt);
    echo "amt is not float: ".$amt;
}

if(fmod($amt2,1) >  0)
{
     echo "<br />amt2 is float: ".$amt2;
}
else
{
    $amt2 = intval($amt2);
    echo "<br />amt2 is not float: ".$amt2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cast the value into float and check if is float. try this

edit: after cast to float check if value is a number or not..

```
if(is_float((float)$payableamt)){

    if(is_int($payableamt)){
        print_r("is not float");
    }
    else{
        print_r("is float");
    }
}
```

Comment: same output as i have in 1 st example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether a string is containing a float, rather than if a variable is a float, you can use this simple little function:([reference link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) )

```
  function isfloat($float) return ($float == (string)(float)$float);
```

OR you can use `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`

```
if (filter_var($float, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)){
    print_r("is float");
}else{
   print_r("is not float");
}
```

Comment: same output as i have in 1 st example

Comment: you can try both options ?