# Need to check to enter only float numbers in php?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I want to validate and that the user only enters float number in the text field such as `3.4`. I need to check only the `$value1` and `$value2` in this case using `php`.

libraryForm.php

```
<form action="savelibscores.php" method="POST">
S3: <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="s3" size="5"> <br /><br/>
S4: <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="s4" size="5"> <br /><br/>
<b>Year:<b/>
<select name="year"> 
<option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option> 
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option></select><br/><br/>

<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"><br /><br/>

</form>
```

savelibscores.php

```
<?php

 define('DB_NAME','');
 define('DB_USER','');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','');
 define('DB_HOST','localhost');

 $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

 if(!$connect){
      die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
 }

 $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connect);

 if(!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use'.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
 }

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $value1=$_POST['s3'];
    $value2=$_POST['s4'];
   $value3=$_POST['year'];
 if(!empty($value1) && !empty($value2) && !empty($value3)){
       $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `library`(s3,s4,year) VALUES ('".$value1."','".$value2."','".$value3."')")or die(mysql_error());
}
   else{
    echo "Please fill all the fields.";
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking if a number is float in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866713/checking-if-a-number-is-float-in-php)

Comment: @ Ben N @ chris85 thanks a lot guys!!!

Comment: Also note your SQL is injectable as is. You also should switch to the PDO or mysqli driver. One solution to injection issue is to cast the values as floats, best solution is prepared statements though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options ..

[is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) function

[filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function, with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` filter as second argument.

[floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) or the `(float)`  cast before your variable name.

The first two will check wether or not it's a float, and the third one will convert whatever you give it to a float. I like to use the `filter_var()` function as it makes the code clear, and it,s also very useful to verify all sort of things (emails adress, IP adress, URL, etc).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input type="number" step="0.1">
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5) for more details.