# Validating 'Price' (double) form input PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

Hi i'm trying to validate user input on a form using PHP. 
I have managed to validate text, numeric and year input but can't get price to work.

I create error variables at the top of my code:

```
 $titleErr = ""; $developerErr = ""; $releaseErr = ""; $stockErr = ""; $priceErr = "";
```

I then validate the input and assign a message to the variable if needs be:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$title)) {
                    $titleErr = "Invalid input, only letters and white space allowed.";
                } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$developer)){
                    $developerErr = "Invalid input, only letters and white space allowed.";
                } else if ($release<1990 || $release>2020){
                    $releaseErr = "Invalid input, enter a year between 1990 & 2020.";
                } else if (!is_numeric($stock)){
                    $stockErr = "Invalid input, only numbers allowed.";
                } else if (!is_float($price)){
                    $priceErr = "Invalid input, only doubles allowed.";
                }
```

The first 4 statements validate input perfectly. However the last one that is checking if the input is a float (for price e.g. 10.99) seems to return the error message when I enter correct input.

This is my form:

```
<form class ="form-horizontal" role="form" id="add" name="add" action="?" method="post">           
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Title</label> <div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="addFormTitle" name="title" type="text"> <span class="error"><?php echo $titleErr;?></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Developer</label> <div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="addFormDeveloper" name="developer" type="text"> <span class="error"><?php echo $developerErr;?></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Release (Year Format/YYYY)</label> <div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="addFormRelease" name="release" type="text"> <span class="error"><?php echo $releaseErr;?></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Stock</label> <div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="addFormStock" name="stock" type="text"> <span class="error"><?php echo $stockErr;?></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Price (&#163)</label> <div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="addFormPrice" name="price" type="text"> <span class="error"><?php echo $priceErr;?></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="addSubmit" value="Add product">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: When your browser sends values to PHP (e.g. using GET or POST), **everything** is interpreted by PHP as a string. Even if the value is `1`, this is actually `"1"`. Therefore using `is_float()` will always be false.

Comment: Check out regex for [validating price](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4983648/5509627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `floatval` function to get the float value of a variable and then check whether it's a float value or not, like this:

```
if(is_float(floatval($price))){
    echo "float value";
}else{
    echo "not a float value";
}
```

**Edited:**

In your code you can do something like this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$title)) {
    $titleErr = "Invalid input, only letters and white space allowed.";
} else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$developer)){
    $developerErr = "Invalid input, only letters and white space allowed.";
} else if ($release<1990 || $release>2020){
    $releaseErr = "Invalid input, enter a year between 1990 & 2020.";
} else if (!is_numeric($stock)){
    $stockErr = "Invalid input, only numbers allowed.";
} else if (!is_float(floatval($price))){
    $priceErr = "Invalid input, only doubles allowed.";
}
```

Comment: Good thinking, but this wouldn't work since `floatval('string')` is casted to `float(0)`. So you have no way to tell if the value was *actually* 0 or just entered incorrectly. `is_float(floatval( $any_string ))` is always `true`.

Comment: Ah, good catch. It wouldn't catch 0 as float.

Comment: @user2966455 See my comment above. Try entering an invalid value and I guarantee it's not going to catch it.

Comment: @Mike yes you're correct, how do I rectify this?

Comment: @user2966455, mike is right. I think your [answer lies here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14866782/5517143)